# How to conditionally filter IQueryable by type using generic repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, linq-to-entities

I have a method in my generic repository that returns an `IQueryable<T>`:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> All
    {
        get
        {
            DbSet<T> set = Context.Set<T>();

            if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(OrganisationDependent)))
                return set.AsEnumerable()
                          .Cast<OrganisationDependent>()
                          .Where(x => x.OrganisationID == CurrentOrganisationID)
                          .AsQueryable()
                          .Cast<T>();

            return set;
        }
    }
```

The reason for the if statement is that most, but not all of my tables have an `OrganisationID` and I want to ensure that a user only sees data for the organisation they belong to. The above code works but in order to make it work I had to add the `AsEnumerable()` to pull the data into memory. Without it I get the error message

> "Unable to cast the type 'Models.xxx' to type
>   'Models.OrganisationDependent'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting
>   EDM primitive or enumeration types"

All my entities directly inherit either `ModelBase` or `OrganisationDependent`:

```
public abstract class OrganisationDependent : ModelBase
{
    public int OrganisationID { get; set; }

    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ModelBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way that I can overcome this restriction so that when the type is a sub class of `OrganisationDependent`, I filter on `OrganisationID` without having to pull the query into memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to use the LINQ Expressions API to build a filter expression dynamically:

```
private static readonly PropertyInfo _organizationIdProperty 
    = typeof(OrganisationDependent).GetProperty("OrganisationID");

private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> FilterByOrganization<T>(int organizationId)
{
    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    var propertyValue = Expression.Property(item, _organizationIdProperty);
    var body = Expression.Equal(propertyValue, Expression.Constant(organizationId));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
}

public virtual IQueryable<T> All
{
    get
    {
        IQueryable<T> set = Context.Set<T>();
        if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(OrganisationDependent)))
        {
            var filter = FilterByOrganization<T>(CurrentOrganisationID);
            set = set.Where(filter);
        }

        return set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would expect this to fail at runtime, given that the property access is from a type that doesn't match the parameter.

Comment: @Servy: Nope - the parameter type `T` is derived from the type which owns the property, so the property access will work as expected.

Comment: This does work. I did get a compiler warning "Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'Data.RepositoryBase<T>'" - I am unsure of the reason for the warning but it went away when I renamed it on the method to TOrg - rather obviously. Now I need to go learn about LINQ Expressions API......Many thanks