# Multi-tenant entity filtration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm working on multi-tenant application where different companies are differs by `CompanyID` column. There are also common core tables in database like `Settings` which are the same for all the companies. I have two base persistent classes: `PersistentObject` and `CompanyPersistentObject`. The last one inherits from the first and adds `CompanyId` property. I'm going to insert company ID criteria directly in repository like this:

```
public class EntityFrameworkRepository<T> : Repository<T>
    where T : PersistentObject
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> set;
    private readonly IApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private readonly IQueryable<T> queryable;

    public EntityFrameworkRepository(DbSet<T> set,
                                     IApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        this.set = set;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;

        if (typeof (CompanyPersistentObject).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            // TODO: Apply CompanyPersistentObject filter
            // using applicationContext.CompanyID
        }
    }
}
```

Is this good approach or you can suggest the better solution?
If so how to inject the criteria for `CompanyPersistentObject` in `DbSet<T>` where `T` is `PersistentObject` and have no `CompanyId` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do almost exactly what you are proposing in my application. The method I found trickiest to implement was the "All" wrapper. I wanted to return an `IQueryable` but linq to entities does not support casting to entities. The answer to that problem was provided here:

[How to conditionally filter IQueryable by type using generic repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052827/how-to-conditionally-filter-iqueryable-by-type-using-generic-repository-pattern)

I did actually start out using the technique that Martin Eden suggests, but I re-factored it into a single base repository as you are proposing, and it is now much simpler and safer.

This is what my "Find" method looks like:

```
    public virtual T Find(int id)
    {
        T e = Context.Set<T>().Find(id);

        var od = e as OrganisationDependent;
        if (od != null && od.OrganisationID != CurrentOrganisationID)
            return null;

        if (e == null)
            return null;

        return e;
    }
```

Comment: What about `GetAll(filter)` method?

Comment: I use the `All` method posted at that link I provided above

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you instead extend your EntityFrameworkRepository class with a CompanyRepository class that has this behaviour. Then you could constrain the type parameter of CompanyRepository to only be classes that extend CompanyPersistentObject (or better, an interface).

For example:

```
public class EntityFrameworkRepository<T> : Repository<T>
    where T : PersistentObject
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> set;
    private readonly IApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private readonly IQueryable<T> queryable;

    public EntityFrameworkRepository(DbSet<T> set,
                                 IApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        this.set = set;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}


public class CompanyRepository<T> : Repository<T>
    where T : PersistentObject, ICompany
{
    public CompanyRepository(DbSet<T> set,
                                 IApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        this.set = setFilteredById(set, applicationContext.CompanyId);    
    }
}
```

Comment: The matter is all the repos are registered automatically by DI framework. In your case I'll need to register them manually.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks by the way. Will think how to rewrite repo registration.