# Entity Framework Generic Predicate

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I need to share a predicate over 4-5 difference entity sets preferably without duplicating the code. All of the entities implement the interface `IEntity`.

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetUpdatedPredicate<T>(DateTime? lastUpdated) where T : IEntity {
    if (lastUpdated.HasValue) {
        return x => (
            x.CreatedAt >= lastUpdated ||
            (x.UpdatedAt.HasValue && x.UpdatedAt >= lastUpdated)
        );
    }

    return x => true;
}
```

Then used like this, across multiple entity sets:

```
(
     from s in Db.EntityA.Where(GetUpdatedPredicate<EntityA>(lastUpdated))
     where (
         s.User.Id == 1
     )
     select s
 ).Future();
```

But gives the error:
*Unable to cast the type 'EntityA' to type 'IEntity'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.* Is there a way to do this without duplicating the code?

Comment: I think you are trying to do something similar to what I was trying to do and hitting the same problem I had. I was trying to filter by Organisation, you are trying to filter by User. Have a look at the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20052827/150342

Comment: That does work, but so does @Moeri's solution... which IMO is much nicer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework has issues with your interface type constraint here:

```
where T : IEntity
```

You need to add an additional constraint that T needs to be a class:

```
where T : class, IEntity
```

Also, if you're starting to discover LINQ expressions, I can highly recommend the [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) library. It has some really, really nifty stuff.

Comment: You literally answered the question just as I'd finished writing it using the expression builder (ie.) `Expression.Parameter(.....)`. But your answer is correct. Starting to discover LINQ expressions? I'm insulted ;) But I haven't stumbled across LinqKit yet so thanks :)

Comment: Hey hey, I said "if" :) I ran into the same problem very early while I was discovering expressions myself,  hence my assumption. LinqKit is pretty great by the way, you should be able to avoid most of the manual expression building simply by using the .Invoke() and .Expand() pattern LinqKit provides.

Comment: +1. i also highly recommend linqkit and have used the predicatebuilder in many corner cases where nothing else would fit. can't say enough good things about that. oh and also, good answer of course :-) `if`

Answer (score 0):

I am proposing an alternative approach.

Firstly, instead of having a method to return an expression, you will have a private static method like:

```
private static bool Evaluate(IEntity x, DateTime? lastUpdated) {
    if (lastUpdated.HasValue) {
        return x.CreatedAt >= lastUpdated ||
            (x.UpdatedAt.HasValue && x.UpdatedAt >= lastUpdated)
        );
    }

    return true;
}
```

Obviously you can name the mention better. Then use it like:

```
var result = Db.EntityA.Where(i => i.Evaluate(i, lastUpdated));
```

Comment: EF still won't be able to translate an expression which contains a .net method to sql.

Answer (score 0):

EF now tries to include the call to your method into the generated expression, and that will not work. You have to exclude the method-call from the expression.

Try to create the expression from your method before you define your query (no, I haven't tested it).

```
DateTime lastUpdated = ...;
var updatedPredicate = GetUpdatedPredicate<EntityA>(lastUpdated);
var query = 
(
     from s in Db.EntityA.Where(updatedPredicate)
     where (
         s.User.Id == 1
     )
     select s
 ).Future();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same result :S

Comment: With @Moeri's answer, you can still use .Where(GetUpdatedPredicate<EntityA>(lastUpdated)) :)